# SQL query, find the user that does not have bank_account

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL query, find the user that does not have bank_account

I have two tables, the first one is table  bank_customer, and the other is table user.
The table of bank_customer has many columns, including user_id and bank_account.
in table user, I have column id.

not every user has bank_account. so I want to query, users that do not have a bank_account, but it gets hard.

```
SELECT * FROM users, bank_customers
WHERE NOT users.id=bank_customers.user_id
```

so how can I query in SQL with this case?

and how to logic that case? for the next case I can find out by myself.

Comment: Take a look at `NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: Also, don't use the antiquated ANSI-89 joins. Use: `FROM users u INNER JOIN bank_customer bc ON bc.user_id = u.id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about that, but the simplest way would probably be using `IN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM bank_customers
)
```